# Trimming then adding text

Tags: reporting-services

I have an output in my queries that gives me:

xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx : 123456 (xx) - xxxxxxx...

or

xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx : 12345678 (xx) - xxxxxxx...

basically text before either a 6 or 8 digit number then text after

I've created a column in a table in SSRS that just shows the number, and I used this expression:

```sql
=Mid(Fields!my.Value,InStr(Fields!my.Value,":")+1,Instr(InStr(Fields!my.Value,":")+3,Fields!my.Value," ") - InStr(Fields!my.Value,":") -1)
```

Which now gives me an output of 123456 or 12345678. Which is great.

However I'd like to do an additional thing. I'd like to create an output that if the digit is 6 numbers long returns London and if the digit is 8 numbers long then it returns Paris .  Is this possible - I've researched and tried with:

```sql
=IIF(Len(Mid(Fields!my.Value,InStr(Fields!my.Value,":")+1,Instr(InStr(Fields!my.Value,":")+3,Fields!my.Value," ") - InStr(Fields!my.Value,":") -1))=8,"Paris",IIF(Len(Mid(Fields!my.Value,InStr(Fields!my.Value,":")+1,Instr(InStr(Fields!my.Value,":")+3,Fields!my.Value," ") - InStr(Fields!my.Value,":") -1))=6,"London","Wrong Number"))
```

But sadly that just gives me 'wrong number' so I'm close but no cigar. I'm sure this expression just needs a final tweak but can't quite get there. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I would tend to do this sort of thing in the query as a case expression.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. If there wasn't all the text around the numbers I'd agree but I'm not sure if it's possible to CASE this. See the top of the post for the volume of text that appears. There's a lot. Is it possible to CASE and trim out all the text - just focus on the number? The number is either 6 or 8 digits and needs digging out - as per the expression above. I'd nearly cracked it with the expression.

Comment: It may be faster doing it server side. If you post some example records with how you want it to look, I'll give the Case expression a crack in about 8 hours

Comment: Appreciated, thanks. The output is essentially as above, returning 'London' if there are 6 digits and Paris if there are 8 digits. The normal output (with x = a textual character) is either: xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx : 123456 (xx) - xxxxxxx...

or

xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx : 12345678 (xx) - xxxxxxx...

Comment: I managed to work out a CASE statement and got it sorted: case 

   when MyColumn like '%TEST[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' then 'Test'

   when MyColumn like '%[^0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' then 'Paris'

   when MyColumn like '%[^0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' then 'London'

else 'Unknown' end as Result    - thanks for your offer of help, much appreciated

Comment: No worries, glad to hear you got it working

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your best and easiest solution is to use the `Len` function on the value in the actual textboxes using `ReportItems!`.  I'd also recommend using the `TRIM` function to cut out any unintended spaces that could skew your `Len` count. 
 Rather than repeat the same expression to isolate the number, you should be able to simplify the second expression like the following.

```
=IIF(Len(Trim(ReportItems!CodeTextbox.Value)) = 6, "London", 
     IIF(Len(Trim(ReportItems!CodeTextbox.Value)) = 8, "Paris", "Wrong Number")
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back. Much appreciated. I managed to somehow work out a CASE statement to sort this out. When I tried your expression however it just came through as 'wrong number', oddly.